# Which is the command to query a Subversion repository for all files locked by a specific user?

Tags: svn

Which is the command to query a Subversion repository for all files <strike>checked out to</strike> locked by a specific user?

Comment: checked out in VSS means the same as locked means in SVN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In subversion "*checked out*" merely means that you have made a local working copy of some folder in the repository. You can then work off-line on this working copy (until you need to do some operation that requires communication with the repository).

While off-line you could delete your working copy at any time, so there really is no way for the server to know who still has something "checked out" and who hasn't.

---

**edit**: So you meant locks. To list everything locked by a specific user, you can use a bit of svn+xml+xslt voodoo. First, create an svninfo.xml file like this:

```
    svn info -R --xml http://url/to/project/root >> svninfo.xml
```

Add this xslt stylesheet pre-processor element in the result file after `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

```
     <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="svnlocks.xsl" ?>
```

Create an svnlocks.xsl file with this content, replace `username` by the actual username:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html><body>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="info/entry[lock/owner='username']" />
      </body></html>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="entry">
      <xsl:value-of select="@path"/><br/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Finally, open svninfo.xml with your favorite
    browser.

Comment: I just corrected this, checked out in VSS means the same as locked means in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

use [svn status](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) to get a listing of all files locked by a user - by that I mean, all files that have the [svn:needs-lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html) property set, and a user has acquired those locks using the [svn lock](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.lock.html) command.

If you're using the command line, you'll see an O marker on each file that is locked, run svn status --show-updates. To find out who has that file locked, use [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html). (note, if you have a file locked, svn status will show K).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to search for files *locked* by a specific user?  Because you can't search for files checked out by a particular user (without raiding that user's home directory).

Comment: I just corrected the question, checked out in VSS means the same as locked means in SVN

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use `svnadmin` on the repository machine, then you can use `svnadmin lslocks <repo>` to get details of all locks held on that repository. From there, you could write something to filter by username.

See [The Subversion Book: Advanced Locks (Breaking & Stealing Locks)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.break-steal) for more information.